# AJAX to dynamically fetch data from a file not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm Using AJAX to dynamically fetch data from my php page and display it on a html page. Its not working. Here is the [link to the page](http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/blog-post.html#)

```
HTML Page where the call is made and result should be displayed
    <h3><a href="#" id="get">John</a></h3> 
    <div> 
        <p class="post">Result to be displayed</p> 
    </div>
```

AJAX code

```
   $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    //  load() functions

    var loadUrl = "../load.php";
        $("#get").click(function(){
        $(".post")
            .html(ajax_load)
            .load(loadUrl, "language=php&version=5");
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

var loadUrl = "../load.php";
        $("#get").click(function(){
            $(".post")
                .html(ajax_load)
                .load(loadUrl, "language=php&version=5");
        });
});
```

Is pretty much what you want.

Comment: @dragonfly found your next problem, you are referencing your own javascript before jQuery. Test with firebug/webkit dev tools first next time.

Comment: It should also be inside a block of $(function(){ codehere });

Comment: @dragonfly Updated answer with fix

Comment: @dragonfly ajax_load is undefined